# Programmatically change Required background modes

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have an app that need Location Based Services in the background.
So in info.plist I setrRequired background modes to "App registers for location updates".
and everything works fine.

My question is, how can I disable it running in background?
Is it possible to add an option and let users set it on/off?

As I know info.plist can not be change programmatically
so how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is the description - it supports registering for location updates.  So all you should have to do is tell your location manager to stop updating when the app goes into the background (or before) and it should then not be using location updates in the background.

There is no way to re-define the info.plist abilities of the app at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally (and pragmatically) you would set up your location manager to -startUpdatingLocation while your app is in use. This will drain your battery pretty quick if you leave it running full time. Typically you would call this, get the information you need, or update information, the call -stopUpdatingLocation. This puts everything to rest, no more battery drain.

When rolling over to the background, you have very limited options for accuracy if you still want to preserve battery life. The main one is -startMonitoringForSignificantChanges. This location update relies primarily on cell tower hand offs and triangulation. So if your user isn't moving large distances or is in an area with limited cell reception, don't expect this background mode to work very good.

You other background option is -startMonitoringRegion. This allows you to create a circle based region around places and get notifications when you -enterRegion or -exitRegion. These all have to be set up before entering the background. They do have the added benefit of better location updates. WiFi changing, cell tower handoffs, and even other apps using location updates. The OS grabs all locations updates and funnels them down and makes them available to any regions registered with the OS.

You still have the option to run location updates live in the background, but your users will not be thankful that they have no battery after 30 minutes of use.

Good luck. There are plenty of examples how to achieve all of these on SO and the web. The trick is finding the right combination that will work for you. Good Luck.

Comment: thanks ,becase the battery life , and even user close the app, the gps icon is still there. so i want to give an option that use can chose is the gps keep running in background.